# Custom Mediaplayer Video Android quality option like Youtube

Tags: android, youtube, media-player, surfaceview, android-videoview

I am creating a Video Player Application with custom User interface using MediaPlayer with Surfaceview , the video is playing through url everything is working fine , now i want to add video quality option like 540p , 720p etc I have url of different quality to play same video but with different resolution but i dont know how i can change Datasource of playing video to set url of desired resolution  at runtime and change  it and play it from where it is resumed just like Youtube.. I tried following code

```
  mp.setDataSource(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(params[0])));
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
```

by using this video is playing but when i try to change Datsourec again by passing new url to

```
mp.setDataSource(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(params[0])));
```

It gives me IllegalstateException.. i tried to release and reset Medaiplayer but not able to do it .. Any Help would be beneficial.